# GeoTools How to add attribute to a schema in DataStore

Tags: postgresql, fields-attributes, geotools

As you know, you can create a schema in a DataStore. For example, you may create a table in a *postgresql* database like this:

```
SimpleFeatureType schema = ...;// some schema
DataStore dataStore = ...;// A Postgresql DataStore
dataStore.createSchema(schema); // creates a table in
```

A challenge is that is it possible to modify a postgresql table adding some columns or changing column names **By GeoTools**.

Comment: So you are not going to answer. Apparently GeoTools does not have this feature.

Comment: How many times do I need to say feature types are immutable, this means you can not change them.

Comment: I'd not like to change featureType object. I want to add a column in database table by GeoTools.